# Mysql - make unique constraints on both fields

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using mysql (mariadb).
I have one table "events_ratings", which contains 4 columns

```
CREATE TABLE `event_ratings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_event` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` char(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY `id`,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `idevent` FOREIGN KEY (`id_event`) REFERENCES `events_fb` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `iduser` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The aim of this table is to provide user rating, so :

- Each user can rate an event (based on his unique "id_user"). The user could rates many events as he wants but never the same one.

So basically id_user AND id_event should never have duplicated values.
I know how to make a column unique but how to make a constraint based on two fields ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to add a unique constraint and specify both fields in it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `events_rating` ADD UNIQUE `unique_user_event`(`id_user`, `id_event`);
```

Comment: Thank you ! What if I want to erase last value and update with the new value on update ? For now it works fine but the user can't update its rating. Any clue ?

Comment: @yoann84 hey, try smth like `INSERT INTO events_ratings VALUES(<put your values here>) as new ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE ratings=new.ratings`. This one will try to insert a new row, if duplicate met it will replace old ratings with new ratings.